# Non linear mixed effect coding in R

Tags: r, mixed-models

In R I wish to perform non linear mixed effect models by assigning the terms `QY`, `ALOS` and `expenditure` as fixed variables and `Month` as a random variable. Is this the right format to perform the analysis? (Note : `QY` stands for quality of life, `ALOS` refers to average length of stay, `Expenditure` refers to the total expenditure borne by the patient during his surgery, `DC` refers to direct cost and `IC` is the indirect cost)
The dataset looks like :

```r
> head(sur_2019)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Month     ALOS Expenditure    IC    DC   QY
  <chr>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 January   3.2        17800  4560 13240 0.0984
2 February  4.86       26790  5000 21790 1.08  
3 March     4.2        42500  7500 35000 0.843 
4 April     3.5        25000  5850 19150 0.234 
5 May       3.5        80000 16100 63900 0.385 
6 June      3.07       22780  6780 16000 0.120
```

Analysis:

```r
m1<-lme(QY~ALOS+Expenditure+Month,
          data=sur_2019, fixed=QY~ALOS+Expenditure, 
          random=~1|Month, na.action = na.omit,
          start=c(QY=1, ALOS=1, Expenditure=100))
```

> 1. Error in lme(QY ~ ALOS + Expenditure + Month, data = sur_2019, fixed = QY ~  :
>    unused argument (start = c(QY = 1, ALOS = 1, Expenditure = 100))

> 2. Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) :
>    Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1

Comment: Hi, it is impossible to help you since you don't provide a minimal reproducible exemple : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. At least we need to know what does your dataset look like

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the clarification required @Bastien Ducreux . I have edited my question. Please have a look and in case you need some more information then I will update it again. Thanks

Comment: This still isn't fully reproducible, but your main problem is most likely that you have specified `Month` both in the fixed and the random effects. Also, you've specified the formula twice. Try something like:  `lme(fixed = QY~ALOS+Expenditure, data=sur_2019,  random=~1|Month)`. You don't need starting values. And, this is a *linear* mixed model, not a *nonlinear* model.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question which now looks in a more presentable form. @BenBolker. Sir I have understood that it is first of all it is the case of linear mixed model and on applying the above commands I get the following error :  m1<-lmer(QY~ALOS+Expenditure+(1|Month),data=sur_2019)
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: Month). PLease guide further

Comment: We really need a [mcve] to get farther. Guessing: do you only have a single year of data, i.e. 12 observations?